# Append a time series to a list of time series in r

Tags: r, list, time-series

I have  list of products: *P1, P2, P3, P4* belonging to different categories, as per ***df***  *CAT*.
 For each product there are two ***time series*** associated:
*ts_sales* and *ts_ofs* (representing sales and out of stock).

I want to correlate sales time series of *P1* with out of stock of *P2, P3* (belonging to the same category)

This code shows how I correlate ***sales time series*** from products on the same category:

```
rm(list=ls())
CAT <- data.frame(PROD = c('P1','P2','P3','P4'),CAT = c('C1','C1','C1','C2'))
ts_sales <- list()
ts_sales$'P1' <- ts(runif(10,0,1), start=c(2019,1), frequency = 12)
ts_sales$'P2' <- ts(runif(10,0,1), start=c(2019,1), frequency = 12)
ts_sales$'P3' <- ts(runif(10,0,1), start=c(2019,1), frequency = 12)
ts_sales$'P4' <- ts(runif(10,0,1), start=c(2019,1), frequency = 12)
ts_ofs <- list()
ts_ofs$'P1' <- ts(runif(10,0,1), start=c(2019,1), frequency = 12)
ts_ofs$'P2' <- ts(runif(10,0,1), start=c(2019,1), frequency = 12)
ts_ofs$'P3' <- ts(runif(10,0,1), start=c(2019,1), frequency = 12)
ts_ofs$'P4' <- ts(runif(10,0,1), start=c(2019,1), frequency = 12)

sales <- with(CAT,split(as.character(PROD), CAT))
sales <-  lapply(sales, function(x) ts_sales[x])
ofs <- with(CAT,split(as.character(PROD), CAT))
ofs <-  lapply(ofs, function(x) ts_ofs[x])
cor(do.call(ts.intersect, sales$C1))
```

I tried:

```
c(ofs$C1,sales$C1$P1)
```

but *sales$C1$P1* does not get appended on the same format

Appreciate :)

Comment: mistake, it should be ofs.  I rewrite it. Thanks

Comment: Your `sales$C1$P1` is a time series, while the 'ofs$C1` is just a character vector.  what is the expected output

Comment: ***ofs$C1*** is a list with all the "ofs" time series on category C1

Comment: ok, got it, i was looking at the previous one without the oupdate

Comment: ***do.call(ts.intersect, ofs$C1)*** this same matrix shape with an adinional column with ***sales$C1$P1***

Comment: THe issue is also that the names are same in both elements

Comment: It will create duplicate names

Comment: That´s right. I can avoid duplicating names by removing the one from ofs$C1

Comment: as it will correlate <- no stock no sales ( on the real problem)

Comment: I want to correlate the out of stock from different products on the same family, but no t with itself

Comment: concatenate strips the attributes, but I am trying to think how you would make it with the attributes when they are duplicatess

Comment: That would be interesting, but is´t not really necessary. Thanks Akrun :)

Comment: Are you looking for `do.call(ts.intersect, Map(c, ofs, sales)$C1)`

Comment: It can work. I will just subset the matrix. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
out <- lapply(Map(c, ofs, sales), function(x) do.call(ts.intersect, x))
```